# Inserting into MySQL database, query not running

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple sign up/in form for a school assignment.
for some reason I can't get it to create a new column in my current table.
All of the information for the $_Get is coming up properly. I imagine its a syntax error i'm not seeing. Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
 if ( $_GET['action'] == "create" )

    {

        print('test');
        // -----------------------
        // PERFORM DATABASE UPDATE
        $fn = $_GET['fn'];
        $ln = $_GET['ln'];
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $user = $_GET['user'];
        $tel = $_GET['tel_num'];
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $bday = $_GET['birthday'];
        $password = $_GET['password'];
        $address = $_GET['address'];

        print('test1');

        mysql_select_db("advweb2");


        $sql="INSERT INTO `account` (`user`, `password` , `email` , `first_name` , `last_name` , `address` , `tel_num` , `birthday`)
        VALUES ('$user', '$password', '$email', '$fn', '$ln', '$address', '$tel', '$bday')"; 
        print_r($sql);



        print("<div style='color:green'>update successful</div>");

        // -----------------------

        $action = "signin";
    }
```

Comment: You need to wrap the $sql variable in a mysql_query() function for it to actually run the query, at the moment you just print it out and don't actually process it. This is, provided that you have set the correct values to connect to the database, since there's no evidence of that in your code.

Comment: When I want a query to run I generally find it useful to actually run the query. :I

Comment: +1 for that @Sammitch, haha. Basically, you will need to execute the query.

Comment: @Karl Although I completely agree with your comment, you should *not* suggest using `mysql_query`, even though he uses it himself.  The `mysql` extension is deprecated, and should _not_ be used anymore. Instead it would be better to suggest the use of [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) for this.

Comment: @Tularis Indeed it is, but for the purpose of his "school assignment" I didn't think it was worth pointing it out.

Comment: @Karl good point, hadn't noticed it was just for a school assignment ;)

Comment: @Tularis, Hey, we're only human :)

Comment: Teaching `mysql_query` is really a bad idea, that interface is so awful it's being removed from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the query.

You should be using MySQLi or PDO as detailed [here](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) as mysql_query is deprecated.

Example with mysqli:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO `account` (`user`, `password` , `email` , `first_name` , `last_name` , `address` , `tel_num` , `birthday`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $user, $password, $email, $fn, $ln, $address, $tel, $bday);
$stmt->execute();

/* ... */

$stmt->close()
?>
```

You need to make sure you clean your `$_GET` variables before inserting into the database to prevent SQL injection. A good read: [how to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Yeah I forgot to run the query. Oops. that's what schools for.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use mysql_query, switch to mysqli or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);


$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

$dbh = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysqli or PDO as explained by others but if you insist execute your query like this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `account` (`user`, `password` , `email` , `first_name` , `last_name` , `address` , `tel_num` , `birthday`)
        VALUES ('$user', '$password', '$email', '$fn', '$ln', '$address', '$tel', '$bday')");
```

Because You prepared query and assigned it to the variable but for missed to execute it.